# python win32api in cygwin-1.75

Tags: python, winapi, cygwin, fabric

when i run fabric-0.9.1 in cygwin, it say following error:

```
$ fab test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fab", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Fabric==0.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.5-i686/egg/fabric/main.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.5-i686/egg/fabric/api.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.5-i686/egg/fabric/context_managers.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.5-i686/egg/fabric/state.py", line 125, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.cygwin-1.7.5-i686/egg/fabric/state.py", line 74, in _get_system_username
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

My environment is windows xp+cygwin1.75+Python 2.6.5+fabric-0.9.1.

should I install python win32 package for cygwin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the answer, it is a small bug of fabric. i solve it according the article:
http://atbrox.com/tag/fabric/